# Why is a question about CSS closed as Off-Topic

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

Yesterday I came across this question [Using the abbr element for responsive text change with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59237866/using-the-abbr-element-for-responsive-text-change-with-css). Today I saw the information that the question was closed claiming it was Off-Topic. Could someone point out what are the reasons for this decision?

Comment: Oh, great. Now the miscategorization of "lacks repro code" under "off topic" is going to be *even more confusing*. Sigh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have enough rep to vote to close, the reasons are shown in the new post notice:

> [Edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59237866/edit) to include [desired behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem. This will help others answer the question.

[image]